# How to highlight a button when it is pressed

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

This seems to work, but then the program crashes right after the button get highlighted.

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
    [sender setHighlighted:YES];    
}
```

How should this be diffeent? What would it look like if I wanted to highlight the button if it was not previously highlighted, and return the button to its normal state if it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably do nothing. NSButton in Cocoa handles this for free; it would surprise me if UIButton didn't do the same.

If the answer is not do nothing, it's to set a different [background image](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:) for the relevant [control states](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State). If you're already customizing it, then you'll want to do this anyway.

Either way, you should not handle this in your action.